# AC like representation, it should be obvious, but I can't prove it

Tags: measure-theory, almost-everywhere, absolute-continuity

Let $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and $m$ a nonnegative, bounded measure on $\mathbb{R}$ that almost everywhere has no atoms. Let $g\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and we have 
\begin{align}
f(t)-f(s) = \int_s^t g(r)m(r)\,dr.
\end{align}

I want to show now that for every test function $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ we have
\begin{align}
\int_0^T \partial_t\varphi(r)f(r) \,dr = \int_0^T \varphi g m\, dr
\end{align}

First Try: I get it for step functions in the sense of distributions. But I'm not sure   it is possible to prove the convergence against the derivative of $\varphi$ on the left side, because it is just a weak convergence and $f$ is not smooth.(I also do not know how to show the weak convergence)

Second Try: if $m$ was the Lebesgue measure it would give me that $f$ is 
AC, right? That means the second equation holds? (differentiable a.e. $\Rightarrow$ weak?)

Does someone has an idea how to prove that? or perhaps a link where I could find a solution and cite? 
Thanks in advance !

Comment: actually $g$ should be at least continous and if necessary you can assume that the domain is bounded, i mean replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $[0,T]$

Comment: No, $f$ differentiable almost everywhere does _not_ imply $f'$ is the weak derivative. But if $f$ is AC then the almost-everywhere defined $f'$ _is_ the weak derivative; this follows from the integration-by-parts-for-AC that's proved in most texts on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

The result as stated is false. For example, if $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\Bbb R)$ is equal to $1$ at every point of $[0,T]$ then the identity you want to prove is $\int_0^T gm(dr)=0$, which doesn't follow from the hypotheses. Assuming the notation $\partial_t\phi(r)$ means just $\phi'(r)$, it's true for $\phi\in C^\infty_c((0,T))$ (except of course that you're missing a minus sign that clearly "should" be there, since this is a version of integration by parts):

In that  case we have $$\int_0^T\phi(r)g(r)\,dm(r)=\int_0^T\int_0^r\phi'(s)g(r)\,ds\,dm(r);$$now apply Fubini's theorem:

$$\begin{align}\int_0^T\phi(r)g(r)\,dm(r)&=\int_0^T\int_s^T\phi'(s)g(r)\,dm(r)\,ds
\\&=\int_0^T\phi'(s)(f(T)-f(s))\,ds
\\&=-\int_0^T\phi'(s)f(s)\,ds,\end{align}$$since $\int_0^T\phi'=0$.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot !